# can jekyll build skip markdown file with invalid format and process the rest?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am automating the creation of markdown files to post to github pages, sometimes the generated markdown file contain illegal syntax.

I am wondering if there is a command to tell jekyll/ github pages to skip invalid formatted markdown file that it cannot translate and proceed to build the rest of the files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll in many ways can be seen as a compiler, and compilers are supposed to stop and make a lot of noise when something is broken. There's really no way to get Jekyll to ignore invalid files.